# @OneToMany in different classes pointing to the same entity

Tags: hibernate, jpa, one-to-many

I have two entities (called EntityA and EntityB), with their ID being a randomly generated UUID (so the ID can be considered as globally unique).
Now I want to allow the user to store additional meta-data (called "tags") for A and B, but in the same table "TagValue".

```
@Entity
@Table
public class EntityA {
   @Id
   private String uuid;

   // Optional tags
   @OneToMany
   @JoinColumn(name="object_id", referencedColumnName="uuid")
   private List<TagValue> tags = new LinkedList<TagValue>();

   // other fields
}
```

EntityB is similar for the uuid and tags part.

Now TagValue :

```
@Entity
@Table
public class TagValue {
   @Id
   private String id;

   // Referenced object UUID
   @Column(name="object_id")
   private String objectId;

   // Tag type
   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(nullable=false)
   private TagType type;

   // Value
   @Column(nullable=false)
   private String value;
}
```

If I use schema generation of Hibernate, I get the following error for EntityB:

```
10:47:00,912 ERROR [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) HHH000388: Unsuccessful: alter table TagValue add constraint FK_ijg5p0jl85r50shhygdudcxh4 foreign key (object_id) references EntityA.
```

Is this mapping method supposed to supported by JPA ? If this is the case, is there any way to avoid the constraint generation on TagValue / object_id ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried dropping the DB? The schema auto-generation in Hibernate has a very, very limited functionality, for a real system you **always** need to handcraft the ddl scripts.

Comment: Dropping the schema does not help. But if I have data in TagValue which reference both EntityA and EntityB through objectId, the constraint creation fails for the two tables.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a uni-directional relationship you don't need to specify the referenced column name. That is trying to create a bi-directional relationship, but because you have no `EntityA` object in your `TagValue` object, Hibernate is saying to you 'I'm expecting an `EntityA` object to attach this ID to, but its not here'.

If this doesn't work for you let me know and I'll modify my answer

```
@Entity
@Table
public class EntityA {
    @Id
    private String uuid;

    // Optional tags
    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name="object_id")
    private List<TagValue> tags = new LinkedList<TagValue>();
// other fields
}
```

If you want you could also use a `JoinTable` to separate out the relationship.

```
@Entity
@Table
public class EntityA {
    @Id
    private String uuid;

    // Optional tags
    @OneToMany
    @Join(name="ENTITY_A_TAGS",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="uuid"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn( name="object_id"))
    private List<TagValue> tags = new LinkedList<TagValue>();
// other fields
}
```

Try either one of these methods out. They should work for `EntityB` as well. If you can't get the first one working, try using a join table.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried the first approach, Hibernate still tries to create the foreign key constraints for EntityA and EntityB.
About the second method, I would like to avoid having a join table for each entity that have tags.

Comment: But, don't you want the foreign key? Without two foreign keys (one for EntityA, one for EntityB) you can't have a relationship.

Comment: Indeed, I don't want the foreign keys on the TagValue table for the objectId field. Hibernate tries to do the 
following: 

    - "fk_ijg5p0jl85r50shhygdudcxh4" FOREIGN KEY (object_id) REFERENCES EntityA(uuid)
    - "fk_ijg5p0jl85r50shhygdudcxh4" FOREIGN KEY (object_id) REFERENCES EntityB(uuid)

Comment: So you want the foreign keys stored on `EntityA` and `EntityB` objects? is that right? It sounds like you want a join table really. That way your `TagValue` doesn't store a foreign key, both foreign keys are stored in the join table. Btw, Hibernate will manage the join table transparently. you don't need to do anything to get it to work.